# Difference between .absolute and .abspath

Tags: raku

Is there one? They both yield the same string

```
given 'file.txt'.IO -> $io {
    say $io."$_" for <path abspath absolute>
}

# file.txt
# /Users/Me/file.txt
# /Users/Me/file.txt
```

Comment: According to the documentation, one of them returns a string, the other takes an (optional) argument and returns a path object.

Comment: http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-08-03

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method Path::IO::absolute got a multi candidate that accepts a prefix to be glued in-between the current work dir and the filename or path fragment provided as a Path::IO instance.

```
dd 'file.txt'.IO.absolute('foo');
OUTPUT«"/home/camelia/foo/file.txt"␤»
```

Comment: ok. so then is there any point in ever using `abspath`? seems you could just call `absolute` with or without argument as needed.

Comment: `abspath` is a lazy accessor to the private property `!.abspath`. The latter is used by `absolute` if you don't provide a parameter. Also it's not a multi so it's potentially faster.

Comment: leads me to another question. will post separately

Comment: abspath has been removed. Use absolute. https://github.com/perl6/doc/commit/cc62dd240cdc02abef40bdd188e6adfbd0213834